# Loading JSON file Using Python Utils Library

Tags: python, json, module

I am using the below code to load my json file, but the issue is, the code is a bit slow.

```
 from utils import load_json

 data = load_json('config_1.json') 
 print data
```

I am doing this using the utils library, but I noticed that the utils library takes a while to load and it's slower than other modules. Is there another way to load a JSON file? Or improve the speed of loading the utils library?

Comment: What "utils library" is this?

Comment: as in the release number?

Comment: No, as in what are you referring to and where did you get it from?

Comment: this one [link](https://pythonhosted.org/python-utils/)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import json
json.load(...)
```

Source: 
[python JSON doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)

Comment: thanks for the quick response. I tried your solution, but i got the below message:     
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

do I need to download the library beforehand?

Comment: @Dr.Bake `json.load` expects a file object, not a file name as a string. `with open('config_1.json') as f: data = json.load(f)`

Comment: It returns a dictionary

Comment: I tried your solution @DeepSpace, but I got the below instead:  
File "/home/python/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode                                                                                                                 
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)

Comment: Are you sure your file is a valid json?